After updating SDK to 51 typeorm DataSource isn't working properly
For some reason after I updated Expo Go and expo to SDK 51 I get this error:
 ERROR  [TypeError: _this3.sqlite.openDatabase is not a function. (In '_this3.sqlite.openDatabase(_this3.options.database)', '_this3.sqlite.openDatabase' is undefined)]
Here's my database.ts:
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import User from '../Models/User';
import Message from '../Models/Message';
import Dialogue from '../Models/Chats/Dialogue';
import Tab from '../Models/Tab';
import SelfProfile from '../Models/SelfProfile';
import Folder from '../Models/Folder';
import Channel from '../Models/Chats/Channel';
import Branch from '../Models/Chats/Branch';
import Role from '../Models/Chats/Role';
import Group from '../Models/Chats/Group';
import Chat from '../Models/Chats/Chat';
import MainChat from '../Models/Chats/MainChat';

export const dataSource = new DataSource({
  database: 'messenger.db',
  type: 'expo',
  driver: require('expo-sqlite'),
  entities: [User, SelfProfile, Message, Tab, Folder, Chat, Branch,
    MainChat, Role, Dialogue, Channel, Group],
  synchronize: true,
  dropSchema: true,
  logging: ["error"],
});

My Initialization.tsx:

// some code before

  if (!dataSource.isInitialized) {
    try {
      await dataSource.initialize();
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

// some code after


Before updating this code was working fine. I can also give some additional information about my code, packages etc.
I tried running:
npx expo-doctor@latest
To check if everything is alright with my project.
Also this:
npx expo install --fix
To fix problems with my dependencies.

Same issue(for expo upgrade 50 to 51) was fixed with following configuration over "driver" field:
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite/legacy';
..
..
..
new DataSource({
      type: 'expo',
      database,
      driver: SQLite,


Can you use Android Studio App Inspection to view/edit the database?
